# VB.net log accessed websites?

Tags: vb.net, filter

I've been searching around for a protocol or for something I can use possibly at the network layer that can monitor websites that are being accessed and log them.

For example a user loads google.com in a browser of their choice and my software sits in the background and records this.

To clarify I am not looking to monitor for passwords, nor is this of malicious intent, I'm looking at a way to establish a local internet filter, without using the hosts file that is.

Any suggestions or where to look?

Comment: What about http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore?

Comment: This is why I love SE, I'll check that out now :) Thanks